# mod_rewrite problem with 2 virtual folders

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, pagination

i have a problem to rewrite 2 parameters that are on the same place in a URL.

i want the following URL Structure:
category (No page or letetr is set)
category/page-2 (different page from page 1)
category/e/page-2 (letter and page is set)

The problem is that my second rule is ignored. :(

Here is my code:

```
    RewriteRule ([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)$ index.php?cat=$1&letter=$2 [L,NC]
    RewriteRule ([^/.]+)/page-([^/.]+)$ index.php?cat=$1&page=$2 [L,NC]
    RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ index.php?cat=$1 [L,NC]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second rule isn't being ignored. Instead, anything that matches the second rule will also match the first rule, so the first rule is processed instead (and the `[L]` modifier prevents further processing).

Basically, the second rule is the same as the first, but with the additional condition that the characters `page-` must also exist between the two captured sections. This `page-` portion matches the `([^/.]+)` condition of the first rule, so it will be matched when the first `RewriteRule` is processed.

Try reversing the order of the first two rules.